# How to hide an anchor tag by the #id of the href

Tags: html, css, hide, anchor

I have different anchor tags with href=#ids.I would like a new value of href without the anchor at the end. Meaning, I do not want the anchor to appear on the search bar. However, I would styling of the id to come in to play.

Currently, in my CSS, I have the following styling that will highlight the background of a particular section when you select, let say Spanish link:

CSS:

```
#Espanol:target{
     background-color: #ffa;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[image]

I would like that to still affect the section but not have the anchor to appear in the href.

```css
a[href='##Non-Discrimin'] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance##Non-Discrimin">English</a></li>
```

The reason for the two "##" is I am using coldfusion and site crashes if I just use 1 '#'. Is there another approach I can do to hide the anchors to not display? Currently it displays as follows:

*/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance/#Non-Discrimin*

I would like the anchor to not display at the end:

*/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance/*

Comment: You need to use the ends-with attribute selector: `a[href$=##Non-Discrimin] { display: none; }` Reference: "[Selectors Level 3: Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)."

Comment: you want to replace the href and remove anchor ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No I want to remove the anchor only from the href

Comment: yes, you want to have a new value of href ? without anchor at the end ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Yes correct

Comment: @DavidThomas: I have tried that approach and it still displays it in the end

Comment: ok so they understand wrong your question

Comment: you have to use JS to do this, CSS won't work

Comment: @DavidThomas i think the duplication of the question is wrng here

Comment: @TemaniAfif: How would I do it in JS

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't work for you, it certainly works for me (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge and even Internet Explorer): https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c242hay4/

Comment: try this code `$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('#')[0]);
})`

Comment: @DavidThomas he doesn't want to select, he want to transform the value of href in order to remove the anchor at then end

Comment: don't forget to include jQuery so the code work

Comment: Right, okay; I was misled by the code and somehow missed the specifics of the answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry for the confusing

Comment: So, I've reopened the question; do you want to change the `href` attribute to remove the `id` string from the `href` (so clicking the link navigates to the address `/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance/`)?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes and I will update the question as well because I have css where it highlights particular sections of the page

Comment: It's also a matter of confusing nomenclature. The word in the URL after the # is called a fragment identifier, not an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with pure CSS, you need some JS. Here is a jQuery solution :

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('#')[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance##Non-Discrimin">English</a></li>
```

This will apply to all `a` tag, to be more specific you can change the selector.

Comment: I will try this approach shortly and thank you for your assistance

Comment: yes it works however, in my css, if I select let say english, it will highlight a certain section of the page. it will just direct the user to that page.

Comment: @Robert sorry but i didn't get you .. can you elaborate with an example

Comment: @ Temani: Yeah. So currently, the anchor goes to a particular section of the page and changes the background color of that section to yellow. I will post what I mean

Comment: @Robert yes and since we removed this anchor from the url you won't have this anymore. You want to keep it ?

Comment: So there isn't a way to have those section highlighted but not have the anchor appear in the url?

Comment: @Robert i don't think so. If we remove the anchor he url will get you to the whole page and no more to a specific section so the hightlight won't work

Comment: @ Temani Afif: Darn. Sorry for wasting your time but thank you for a approach to append the url.

Comment: @Robert it's ok there is no waste ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the matching string from the end of the `href` attribute-value you'll need to use JavaScript (or a back-end server-side scripting language if you prefer):

```
// advance apologies for the clunky name
function removeFromAttributeByString(opts) {

  // initialising an object with the default names,
  // albeit all Object key-values are false at this
  // time (but sensible defaults could be used if
  // you prefer):
  let defaults = {
      'needle': false,
      'attribute': false,
      'haystackSelector': false
    },
    haystack;

  // iterating over the keys of the opts Object if supplied,
  // or an empty Object if opts is not supplied (this is simply
  // to prevent an error message in the absence of a supplied
  // Object) using Object.keys() and Array.prototype.forEach():
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(

    // an Arrow function where we supply the current Object-key
    // ('key') to the function, and set the key-value for the
    // defaults Object to be equal to the key-value supplied
    // via the opts Object passed to the function:
    key => defaults[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // here we use the Object.values() method to retrieve an
  //  array of the defaults Object's values, and iterate over
  // that array using Array.prototype.every() with the Boolean
  // argument, testing that every value is Boolean true and,
  // if so, returning true:
  if (Object.values(defaults).every(Boolean)) {

    // here we find all elements that match the supplied CSS
    // selector (defaults.haystackSelector) and then use
    // Array.from() to convert that array-like nodeList into
    // an Array:
    haystack = Array.from(
                 document.querySelectorAll( defaults.haystackSelector )
               );

    // we filter that array, using Array.prototype.filter():
    haystack.filter(

      // using an Arrow function to pass the current element of
      // the array to the function, and if the current element
      // has the supplied attribute (defauls.attribute) it's
      // retained in the returned Array, otherwise it's discarded:
      element => element.hasAttribute(defaults.attribute)

    // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the array
    // of elements retained:
    ).forEach(

      // here we set the attribute-value to the same attribute-value
      // after we remove the supplied text ('defaults.needle') from
      // attribute-value:
      element => element[defaults.attribute] = element[defaults.attribute].replace(defaults.needle, '')
    );

  }

}

removeFromAttributeByString({
  'needle': '##Non-Discrimin',
  'attribute': 'href',
  'haystackSelector': 'a'
});
```

```js
function removeFromAttributeByString(opts) {
  let defaults = {
      'needle': false,
      'attribute': false,
      'haystackSelector': false
    },
    haystack;

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(
    key => defaults[key] = opts[key]
  );

  if (Object.values(defaults).every(Boolean)) {

    haystack = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.haystackSelector));
    haystack.filter(
      element => element.hasAttribute(defaults.attribute)
    ).forEach(
      element => element[defaults.attribute] = element[defaults.attribute].replace(defaults.needle, '')
    );

  }

}

removeFromAttributeByString({
  'needle': '##Non-Discrimin',
  'attribute': 'href',
  'haystackSelector': 'a'
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="/Regal-en-us/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance##Non-Discrimin">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys).
- [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

Comment: @ David Thomas: Thank you for your help. I will look into the references and how this code works

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; though I've read the other answer - and the comments - and I'm still not sure I appreciate precisely what you want; although from the comments to the other answer it seems you you want to remove the `id` from the `href`, but still have the `href` link to that `id` which is, unfortunately, impossible. Although if you can explain *why* you want that particular feature/function we *may* be able to solve that problem for you in a different way. But usually the `href` attribute is never really seen by the user, so I don't understand why it truly matters in this case.